# "Hadoop The Definitive Guide" source code not running

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Can anyone please tell me the detailed steps how to run the source code of this book? I have Eclipse Luna and Ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded the file as zip file of source code.

Comment: do you have hadoop? You will need to follow a series of steps, like those described in this tutorial: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html. Just a notice, it may take more time, than you think... be patient!

Comment: yes i have hadoop 2.6.0 installed and running.Now I am facing problems to configure it with eclipse Luna